# Why is my basic exponent function not working?

Tags: python, exponent

I am trying to take input for an exponent function but it doesn't give an output.

```py
def exp_func(base,exponent):
    result = 1
    for index in range(0,exponent):
        result*=base
    return result

base = float(input("Enter base:"))
exponent = float(input("Enter exponent:"))

print(exp_func(base,exponent))
```

However without any inputs it works fine.

```py
def exp_func(base,exponent):
    result = 1
    for index in range(0,exponent):
        result*=base
    return result

print(exp_func(2,3))
```

What's the issue?

Comment: Please show an example of what happens when you run it as you had intended.

Comment: try to change `float` to `int`. In your first not worked example you are used float, in second worked - int

Answer (score 2):

Range expects integer type, not float.

```
range(10)
#range(1,10)
range(10.0)
#TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Try changing the input to int. Your implementation won't work with non-integers.

```
def exp_func(base,exponent):
    result = 1
    for index in range(0,exponent):
        result*=base
    return result

base = float(input("Enter base:"))
exponent = int(input("Enter exponent:"))

print(exp_func(base,exponent))
```

Also incase you didn't know about the ** operator, it calculates exponents

```
def exp_func(base,exponent):
    return base ** exponent
```

This will work with floats.

Comment: I almost forgot about the `**` operator, you reminded me to add it to my answer lol

Answer (score -1):

Try changing the `float(input('Enter Base'))` and `float(input('Enter Base'))` to `int(input('Enter Base'))` and `int(input('Enter Base'))` as the float() function automatically adds `.0` to your number if a decimal wasn't included.


This is because the `range()` function doesn't function with a decimal so doing the above can fix your problems.


Your question wasn't clear so this is the best answer I can give you with. If you want a better answer, please change your question.


EDIT: Also, if you want exponents that work with decimals, you can use the `**` operator. Example:

```py
3 ** 4
RETURNS: 81
```

Comment: `float("3")` does work. The only problem lies in the argument to `range`. (Didn't downvote, BTW)

Comment: ok, i have changed my answer. I think @oli5679 downvoted? (no offence)

Comment: Lol it's good to preserve voter anonymity, but I didn't downvote :)

Comment: Thanks changing the inputs to int() worked.

Comment: If your question was answered, please check one of the answers to notify the community that this question was answered :)